# Javascript Phone Swap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I've been trying to find a way to do this but, have not found many resources that specifically relate to this situation.

I need a javascript (can make use of Jquery if need be) to swap phone numbers on a site.

- 2 numbers would be specified.  One would show on the site by default.
- The script needs to be able to create a cookie and do this by recognizing a value in the URL string.

---

**For Example:** http://www.site.com/index.html?value=

'*?value=*' would be the value.

---

This URL (with the additional variable) would bring the user to the same site but, the variable in the string would set the cookie and display a different number.  The default number would not be displayed again until the cookies were removed.

Due to the situation with my server, I cannot make use of PHP ( I know, that would make things alot easier :P )

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you finally find the solution!?

Comment: @aSeptik I think so, your script worked perfectly.  Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

**DEMO:**

GO here: http://jsbin.com/imawo4/85

THEN here: http://jsbin.com/imawo4/85/?value=john

include the [jQuery Cookie Plugin](http://stilbuero.de/jquery/cookie/jquery.cookie.js)

then use this:

**HANDLE URL PARAMETER**

```
  $.extend({
        getUrlVars: function(){
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
         for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
          {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
         vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
       }
      return vars;
 },
     getUrlVar: function(name){
     return $.getUrlVars()[name];
     }
  });
```

**MAIN CODE**

```
$(function() {
// SETTINGS
var identity = 'john';
var phone_number_1 = '555-555-555';
var phone_number_2 = '666-666-666';
var redirect = 'http://jsbin.com/imawo4/85/';

//MAIN SCRIPT
var url_query = $.getUrlVar('value');   
var coockie = $.cookie('phone_number');  
var swapped_phone_number = ( coockie == 'VALID' ) ? phone_number_1 : phone_number_2;
if ( url_query == identity && coockie != 'VALID' && url_query != undefined ) {
$.cookie( 'phone_number' , 'VALID' , { expires: 10 } );
window.location.href = redirect;}
if ( url_query != identity && coockie == null && url_query != undefined ) {
$.cookie( 'phone_number' , null );  
alert('INVALID');}
$('#the_one_already_here').text(swapped_phone_number);
});
```

**HTML PART**

```
<body>
<!--/ output numbers /-->
<div id="the_one_already_here"></div>
</body>
```

This should work as expected! ;-)

Comment: @aSeptik

Thanks for your post.  How would I get this to work without the prompt?  Like just have a number, add a variable to the URL, then have a different number?

Comment: of course, the alert was just for Advice you of the change! but you can easily... se the update! ;-)

Comment: @aSeptik

Looks awesome.  The only thing I'm a little confused on is where to define the phone numbers?

Comment: @aSeptik, also where do I enter the variable, for the URL?

Comment: We have defined the COOKIE_NAME for easy access, then regarding the URL variable, this depend on what you are trying to do! from where this swap number come from!?

Comment: @aSeptik

It doesn't really matter, as long as I can specify 2 separate phone numbers in the javascript.

I don't even want the 'swap my number link'.  

For example when I go to test.com/testpage.html I want 555-555-5555 displayed.  When I go to test.com/testpage.html?paid= I want 555-666-6666 to be displayed.  I would want ANY instance of the phone number on the page replaced.

The cookie is to ensure that the number stays the same. Until the cookies are cleared, of course :)

Comment: Ok, Ok! no problem ;-) you don't really need to use a link! for swap! you just need to point your browser to es.: http://mysite.com/?value=myclientname ... see the update!

Comment: @aSeptik , we're getting closer but, I cant test the new code because the page keeps refreshing over and over.

Comment: @aSeptik  That works almost perfectly! :)  The only thing is, the cookie doesnt seem to be working.  After I have visited the page (with the default number) and then entered the value on the new page (with the new number), if I go back to the main page (no value) the number switches back.  It should stay until I clear my cookies.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, then adding the [jQuery Cookie Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) will make this simple. Here's some quick code as an example (note code is untested):

```
var value = window.location.search.match(/[?&]value=(.*?)(&|$)/);
if (value){
    $.cookie("phoneValue", value[1]);
}
if ($cookie("phoneValue")){
    // set innerHTML to $.("phoneValue")
}
```

Comment: @Chad_K

Thanks for your response.  Can you fill in 2 fake phone numbers in the above example?  I'm not 100% sure, where they are supposed to go.